# Calculate integral analytically

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Could this integral be calculated analytically?

$$ \int_0^a \frac{\cos(\omega t+\phi)}{b - \sin(\omega t + \phi)} \, dt $$

So far I solve it numerical. If anyone could hint substitutions or trigonometric...
Thanks.

$a$ and $b$ are positive constants.

Comment: Its very simple question just one has to substitute x as the denominator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $u = b-\sin(\omega t + \phi)$

$$A = \int_0^a \frac{-du}{u} = -\ln(|u(a)|) + \ln(|u(0)|)$$
$$A = \ln\left(\frac{|u(0)|}{|u(a)|}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{|b-\sin(\phi)|}{|b-\sin(\omega a + \phi))|}\right)$$

Comment: Many thanks for it :)